# Access denied error when creating lambda event source mapping with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an existing DynamoDB table with stream enabled. I am trying to deploy a lambda function and add dynamodb as trigger using Terraform.

I started with restricted permissions and got AccessDenied error with aws_lambda_event_source_mapping. So I finally gave all the permissions on lambda and DynamoDB for that role, just for testing. But I am still getting access denied error.

> Error creating Lambda event source mapping: AccessDeniedException

Lambda function is deployed successfully. I can confirm that stream_arn for dynamodb table is also accurate.

Here is my terraform script:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_name_role" {
    name = "lambda_name_role-test"

   assume_role_policy = <<EOF
   {
       Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
      {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
           "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Sid": ""
      }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function_name" {
  filename      = "./file.zip"
  function_name = "lambda-function-name-test"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_name_role.arn
  handler       = "parse.handler"

  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("./file.zip")
  memory_size      = 512
  timeout          = 10
  runtime          = "nodejs12.x"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_dynamodb_access" {
  name        = "lambda_dynamodb_access_policy_test"
  path        = "/"
  description = "IAM policy for DynamoDB access from lambda"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect":"Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "dynamodb:*",
                    "lambda:*"
                ],
                "Resource":"*"
            }
        ]

}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_dynamodb_policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_name_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_dynamodb_access.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_cloudwatch_policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.name
  policy_arn = var.cloudwatch_policy_arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "lambda_trigger_dynamodb" {
  event_source_arn  = var.dynamodb_table_stream_arn
  function_name     = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function_name.arn
  starting_position = "LATEST"
}
```

Thank you for your help.

---

Update:
I am able to reproduce this error using AWS CLI.

```
aws lambda create-event-source-mapping --event-source-arn <dynamodb-stream-arn> --function-name <lambda-function-arn> --enabled --starting-position LATEST
```

Received AccessDeniedException.

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateEventSourceMapping operation: User: <my-arn> is not authorized to perform: lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping on resource: * with an explicit deny
```

But I am able to add this mapping from AWS Console.

Comment: What policy does your IAM user or role have? There are specific permissions you need to set up event source mappings. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-api-permissions-ref.html#permissions-resources-eventsource

Comment: Are you running the terraform script with a user that have permission to add event source mappings? 
Also can you try adding a time delay before "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping"? If that work you will need to add a dependency untill the lambda resource is fully available.

Comment: @jaredready I am an admin on the account and this script is running using Security Credentials created under my account.

Comment: @Geeshan I tried created all other components first and then run the event source mapping separately. But no luck.

Comment: Can you create the event source mapping between the lambda and table manually in console for tests? This at will confirm that you can create such a mapping, and also should produce extra error messages if there are some permission issues.

Comment: @Marcin yes, I tried that and I am able to create it in the console.

Comment: If so, can you check the lambda execution role? Console will modify it, so you should be able to see what exactly it requires.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the advise. I did that, but I didn't see any change. Even the Policy Versions tab in the policy doesn't show any change.

Comment: @Marcin I tried creating trigger on a different lambda from the console where the role do not have permissions on dynamodb.  Console failed to created the trigger. But the role I am using with the lambda in the questions above, has full permissions for all dynamodb resources. May be this is something related to account permissions, as suggested earlier. But not sure how to track it down.